# How to copy couple of files at once using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Tags: python, c#

I'm creating a sftp_client application using python+QT, and decided to use C# `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` library in order to have files operation with Windows UI options(like window Dialog Box while copying a file with the same name), pretty much as it is made in WinSCP.

I compiled C# code to **dll** and using it in python code, and everything works just fine. But it seems to me that FileIO can copy just 1 file at once, which results in(in case of copying files that already exist) a file dialog window appearing to handle every file instead of appearing 1 time to ask what to do to all files.

C# code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

[DllExport]
        public static OPERATION_STATUS copy_file(String src, String dst)
        {
            if (File.Exists(src))
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(src + " : " + dst);
                    FileSystem.CopyFile(src, dst, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs,
                                                  Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing);
                    return OPERATION_STATUS.SUCCESS;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return OPERATION_STATUS.FAILED;
                }
            }
            return OPERATION_STATUS.FAILED;
        }
```

Python code:

```
import ctypes
a = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(path_to_dll)
result = a.copy_file(str.encode(src),str.encode(dst))
```

In result i get Windows Box for each file

[image]

But I want to get 1 Box  Dialog for all files

[image]

Comment: Without code we can't tell you the problem

Comment: Please take the [tour], and read the [ask] pages. Then post minimum reproducible code.

Comment: @Slugsie thanks for advise, now should be just fine

Comment: `FileSystem.CopyDirectory` maybe?

Comment: @Charlieface apparently,not